# Dependency Service Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

i have a silly question regarding DependencyService. I am developing  a mobile application in Xamarin Forms. I have just been reading about Dependency Service. If I am correct which i am most likely not and please correct if I am not, Dependency service is a class that is responsible for "translating" difference between droid and ios and its used for custom rendereds? So do i have to implement it in my solution?

My situation is that I am currently already connected to SQLite and I followed some tutorial which did not inform me about dependency service and this is how  i initiate the SQL connection in my class.

```
 public UserService()
        {
            _conn = DependencyService.Get<ISQLiteInterface>().GetSQLiteConnection();
            _conn.CreateTable<User>();

        }
```

If I implement interface dependencyservice will that somehow affect my sql connection?

Comment: DependencyService is not something magic. The DependencyService provided by Xamarin it's just a service locator that allows you to resolve your dependencies. As all the dependency injector instruments you need to register your dependencies with this service and then retrieve what you have registered still using this service. You should take a look at what Dependency Injection is. DependencyService it is just an implementation of this pattern.

Comment: Hi, thank you for you answer. I never thought that anything will just magically appear. I will have a look on Dependency injection.

Comment: Is `ISQLiteInterface` from a nuget or are you creating this class on your project? Can you provide more information on the corse you are following, it could help to understand the context.

Answer (score 1):

All dependency service will not have implementation on android and ios. Dependency service is a way to hold single memory location. In this scenario all the functions related to sql connection is implemented in forms .net standard library. So it hold a single memory location, you can call the function anywhere from your project without creating the object. But the key thing is that you should register the dependency service

Comment: So I shpuld create my interface iDependecyService and then add it to both platforms

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Comment: I havem but i will have a look again